# Is it possible to use a keyword name from **kwargs to filter my data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, keyword-argument

Apologies if the title is a bit obscure, I am happy to change it..

***Problem:*** I am trying to use a keyword name in the following code to filter by column name in a dataframe using pandas.

```
@staticmethod
def filter_json(json, col_filter, **kwargs):
    '''
        Convert and filter a JSON object into a dataframe
    '''
    df = pd.read_json(json).drop(col_filter, axis=1)
    for arg in kwargs:
        df = df[(df.arg.isin(kwargs[arg]))]
    return df
```

However I get error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'arg'` because `arg` is not a valid column name (makes sense) at line `df.arg.isin(kwargs[arg]))]`

I am calling the method with the following...

```
filter_json(json_obj, MY_COL_FILTERS, IsOpen=['false', 0])
```

Meaning `df.arg` should essentially be `df.IsOpen`

***Question:*** Is there a way to use `arg` as my column name (`IsOpen`) here? Rather then me having to input it manually as `df.IsOpen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access columns with `dataframe[columnname]` notation as well: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Try:

```
for arg in kwargs:  # arg is 'IsOpen'
        df = df[(df[arg].isin(kwargs[arg]))]  # df['IsOpen'] is same as df.IsOpen
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: You might wanna check if the body of the loop is correct. You're overwriting the `df` variable for each keyword-argument.

Comment: I have just run it and it is filtering as expected with multiple criteria. Eg. `filter_json(json_obj, MY_COL_FILTERS, IsOpen=['false', 0], Disabled=['true', 1])` returns anything that is not open and disabled.